# How to cast long unsigned to unsigned char*?

Tags: c, casting

I am trying to hash an `unsigned long` value, but the hash function takes an `unsigned char *`, as seen in the implementation below:

```
unsigned long djb2(unsigned char *key, int n)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n-8) {
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
    }
    while (i < n)
        hash = hash * 33 + key[i++];
    return hash;
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve my goal, perhaps with a cast between the two?

Comment: reinterpret_cast, but it's ugly. What hashing function requires char*?

Comment: @Pubby, `reinterpret_cast` is C++, the question is for C.

Comment: it might just be me, but I think that there should be more context ( ie more code ) in this question.

Comment: @druciferre It wasn't tagged when I commented ;)

Comment: @Pubby, sorry it didn't show the "Edited" notification on the question (weird).

Comment: @James please, at least, show us the function

Comment: from a look at the function, you better hope that your long is 8 bytes long. otherwise use long long. otherwise you might get segmentation errors

Comment: @TaylorFlores No, he won't

Comment: @TaylorFlores: That comment is completely unfounded. What happens when `n` is 7?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis yeah you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
unsigned long x;

unsigned char * p = (unsigned char*)&x;
```

Make sure you use all 4 bytes through the `p`, or whatever is the length of `unsigned long` on your system.

Comment: what do you mean by "use all 4 bytes through the p"? sorry, I am new to c

Comment: And also, don't forget about endian issues! You might get different hashes for the 'same' data on different machines if you don't swap endian appropriately.

Comment: p is a pointer. It points to the first byte of your unsigned long. In this case a variable named 'x'. I guess you have a function taking an usnigned char pointer and some length. If that's the case, the length should be sizeof( usnigned long ), or sizeof( x ).

Comment: @MattPhillips That's assuming the hash function takes a null terminated string as input. Usually, hashing functions take a length parameter and buffer pointer, not a null terminated string.

Comment: @tangrs Okay I am removing my comment.

Comment: @Matt Phillips, how the hell did you bring string termination in this story?

Comment: @MattPhillips I don't know anyone knows if the function requires a null termination since we have not seen the function yet. A char * doesn't always mean string

Comment: Could I modify the long value by using *p?

Comment: Yes, you can because you defined 'key' as unsigned char *, not as const unsigned char *, but do you really want to do that? You have to properly handle the little endian vs. big endian issue in that case. Btw, maybe you want to execute the while loop only in this case "if( n >= 8 )"?

Comment: Ignore the end of the previous comment, I wasn't using my brain while I was writing that n >= 8 part.

Comment: also, would this be able to serve as a hash function for ints, shorts, and longs? meaning would the hash values be compatible

Comment: @James The hash function could be use on any type, but the hash of the same value won't be the same, it will depends on the size of the type. The hash of a `short` will iterate at least twice while the hash of a `long` will iterate at least 4 times.

Comment: unsigned int also can convert using this way

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can achieve it with:

```
unsigned long value = 58281;
djb2((unsigned char *) &value, sizeof(value));
```

Mind the usual pitfalls, however:

- The hash function in question was originally meant for strings (hence the prototype), so make sure it fits your needs (# of collisions, avalanching, etc.)
- If at some point you want to hash very large objects for which `sizeof(object) > (int) sizeof(object)` (if applicable on your architecture(s)), note you might get out of bounds accesses (undefined behaviour) or only part of your object hashed.

Comment: I think `sizeof x` instead of `sizeof(x)` is even rarer than `return(x) `instead of `return x` :)

Comment: I actually find it refreshing :)

Answer (score 1):

As other said, you can easily read an `int` or any other object as a `char` array :

```
unsigned char value = 0xde;
unsigned short value = 0xdead;
unsigned long value = 0xdeadbeef;
double value = 1./3;

djb2((unsigned char*)&value, sizeof value);
```

But note that `0xdead` stored in a `short` or a `long` **won't have the same hash**.

Also note that your hash function could be better unrolled using a [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) :

```
unsigned long djb2(unsigned char *k, int size)
{
    unsigned long h = 5381;
    int i = 0;
    switch(size % 8) {
      case 0: while(i < size) { 
                  h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 7:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 6:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 5:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 4:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 3:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 2:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
      case 1:     h = h*33 + k[i++];
              }
    }
    return h;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows a cast working.  Note that in this case the "ABC" string will be null terminated but this may require more care in real world cases

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned long x=0x414243;  #0x414243 is ABC
    unsigned char *s=(unsigned char *)&x;
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Comment: In your example, it'll be `ABC` but only on big endian systems. Edit: Actually, on big endian systems, it would just be a empty string.

Comment: yeah, it's "CBA" here on a typical intel Linux system :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you've posted your code now, you'd want to use something similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    unsigned long result, x = 0xdeadbeef;
    x = convert_endian(x);

    result = djb2((unsigned char*)&x, sizeof(x));
    do_something(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @icepack it still loops with less than 8 bytes but produces segmentation faults. in that way, it does expect a buffer of size % 8 == 0

Comment: @TaylorFlores Look closer, it won't loop if size < 8.

Comment: yeah i did, you're right about that. but it can still produce segmentation faults when size % 8 != 0

Comment: @TaylorFlores How? It will loop in multiples of 8 until `n-8` and after that will loop with single steps over whatever remains.

Comment: ugh, yeah you're right. I guess I should test my suggestions more often. I do still think that the first while loop is unnecessary

Comment: @TaylorFlores That's probably for performance optimization (a sort of loop-unrolling)

Comment: you could have just agreed with me and restored my dignity :P interesting though, I've never header of loop-unrolling

Comment: Oh that actually makes a lot of sense. I didn't know c loops had that much overhead

Answer (score -2):

You should convert it using [ultoa_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kk8w4t5t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: he never said string. the question is about casting data types

Comment: Can't you convert ulong to a null-terminated character string and use the pointer?

Comment: @dizzer: How do you expect `0x10000010` to look like as a 0-terminated string?

Comment: @dizzer you have assumed that char * is a string and it might not be. you also have showed the user a function that converts a ulong into a string representation of a number - that is not casting

Comment: @TaylorFlores you are right, char* doesn't mean it is string needed.

Comment: With the snippet of code added by the question author, the answer I gave makes no sense now.